# Postgres logging exclude system schema for CSV logs

Tags: postgresql, logging

How can I collect postgres query usage logs including query duration as a CSV file?
So far I am using the following configuration parameters of Postgres:

```
log_statement=all
logging_collector=on
log_destination=stderr,csvlog
log_directory=pg_log
log_truncate_on_rotation=on
log_rotation_age=1d
log_rotation_size=0
log_duration=0
log_filename=postgresql-fixed.log
```

But this includes the system schema and thus makes the logfiles blow up considerably.

What I actually want to achieve is to get a list of frequently running queries (and users) including the duration of the queries so I can feed my data catalogue with these details.

How can I fine-tune the Postgres logging configuration to exclude the system schemata?

Comment: Could https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstatstatements.html `pg_stat_statements` be a better solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like the rollover also does not work (and the logfile only keeps growing).

Comment: log_statement =  'mod'  , 
log_min_duration_statement = 0

Comment: But this would not exclude the system schema right? And `mod` would exclude the select statements (queries) `mod logs all ddl statements, plus data-modifying statements such as INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE, and COPY FROM. PREPARE, EXECUTE, and EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

Comment: What about post-process your log file using grep or sed, and remove the unnecessary system data

Comment: Perhaps an option. Still it would be ideal if 1) it would not be logged in the first place 2) even more important: I somehow canont get the CSV log file to roll over (it seems to be append-only. Does this mean I would manually need to delete the CSV file once I have parsed it in a downstream service?

Comment: Strangely, even though https://postgresqlco.nf/doc/en/param/log_truncate_on_rotation/ `log_truncate_on_rotation` is set to on` the CSV log file is not getting truncated

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/BD69807DAE0CE44CA00A8338D0FDD0830185A615A8@oma00cexmbx03.corp.westworlds.com `cat /dev/null > postgres_logfile` might be a valida approach though

Answer (score 0):

I am switching to: `pg_stat_statements`. It is much more convenient and also efficient.